# Merge doesn't cascade persist

Tags: hibernate, jpa

Say I have a parent, a child and a child of the child and I need to save the whole hierarchy.

```
@Entity
@Data
class Parent{
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Long id;

    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = {CascadeType.ALL}, orphanRemoval = true)
    public Set<Child> childs = new HashSet<>();
}
```

```
@Entity
@Data
class Child{
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Long id;

    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = {CascadeType.ALL}, orphanRemoval = true)
    public Set<ChildOfChild> childsOfChild = new HashSet<>();
}
```

```
@Entity
@Data
class ChildOfChild{
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Long id;
}
```

If I create the hierarchy and call persist on the parent, the PERSIST operation does cascade to the children as intended.

```java
Parent parent = new Parent();
Child child = new Child(); 
ChildOfChild childOfChild = new ChildOfChild();
child.getChildsOfChild().add(childOfChild);
parent.getChilds().add(child);
```

If I retrieve an existing parent, change its children, and then call merge. The PERSIST operation is not cascaded to its children.

```
parent=findById(id);
Child child = new Child(); 
ChildOfChild childOfChild = new ChildOfChild();
child.getChildsOfChild().add(childOfChild);
parent.getChilds().add(child);
```

Is it normal? How should I cascade persist during a merge operation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the merge operation, that is available through the JPA spec. did not work for my case of nested child.

However the Hibernate specific `SaveOrUpdate` method did the job. If anyone know of any other method available through JPA, please let me know. Meanwhile, this will be the accepted answer.